# Model with autoincremental non PK key

Tags: django, django-models

I'm writing a model where I use an auto incremental key, which is based on two foreign keys and is not the pk.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    message_id = models.IntegerField()
    user_1 = models.ForeignKey(User)
    user_2 = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
         unique_together = ("message_id", "user_1", "user_2")
```

As far as I know, an AutoField can't be used for this case. 
What is the best way to achieve this. (It might be the case, that two new messages are created at the same time).

Comment: Why can't you just use the pk?

Comment: pk can manage your requirement as two new messages are created at same time

Comment: I can't use the pk because I want to check the sequence on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Django [doesn't support composite primary keys](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/373), yet, so best way is pretty much the way you're doing it now.

Keep the automatic id column that Django generates and then add a unique index for the columns that actually are the primary key, the unique index will then take care of ensuring that there's no duplicates.